# How to open in new tab using button

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, tabs

```
<script type="text/html" id="marketSelection">
        <h3 class="choose-store">Choose your store:</h3>
        <div class="text-center">
            <% _.each(suppliers, function (supplier) { %>
            <button class="btn-custom supermarket-item" data-id="<%= supplier.id %>">
                <i></i><%= supplier.name %>
            </button>
            <% }) %>
        </div>

        /*File:src/js/data.js*/
        var cookie_selectedSupermarket = CookieManager.retrieve('supplierId'),
            cookie_selectedPostalCode = CookieManager.retrieve('deliveryareaCode'),
            cookie_q = CookieManager.retrieve('q');
        Data = {
            availabilityList: [JSON_STORE_AVAILABILITY_LIST],
            postalCodes: [JSON_POSTAL_CODES],

            hardCode: {
                selected_supermarket: null,
                selected_postal_code: null,
                q: null
            },
            query: {
                selected_supermarket: Utils.getQueryParameterByName('selected_supermarket'),
                selected_postal_code: Utils.getQueryParameterByName('selected_postal_code'),
                q: Utils.getQueryParameterByName('q')
            },
            cookie: {
                selected_supermarket: cookie_selectedSupermarket ? cookie_selectedSupermarket.value : null,
                selected_postal_code: cookie_selectedPostalCode ? cookie_selectedPostalCode.value : null,
                q: cookie_q ? cookie_q.value : null
            },

            PROTOCOL: 'https://',
            DOMAIN: 'www.test.com.au',
            PATH: '/',
            redirectURI: '/all-products/?supplier=<%= supplierId %><% if (q) { %>&q=<%= q %><% } %>'
        };
```

I have an issue having the buttons open in new tab. In HTML - I know we have to add in _blank but for cases like this, what is the solution?

Thanks

EDIT: Added in more codes so that it's more clear what I want.

Comment: Why is there an `<i></i>`? Is this a template? (where is the `</script>`?) And most importantly: in the code you're showing the generated buttons will do nothing. They're just inert markup. Where's the part that actually makes them supposed open things?

Comment: I've added in more code hoping you guys can figure it out. It's my company's website. It's not my duty nor am I an expert in doing this but we want this to be changed asap so I'm taking charge. Thanks

Comment: that's fairly broken code. How are you starting a new `<script>` tag before closing the original one?

Comment: Is there a particular code that deals with the issue? It's bit too long so I'm not posting the whole code...

Comment: don't post "the whole code", but do post "code that is well formatted, balanced, and a *working example* of what you have". So you remove all the HTML bits that don't contribute, but that still means making sure all the tags etc. are balanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Javascript

```
function openTab(url) {
  var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not getting form url rather, it's generating links it seems? Please have a look at the added codes!

Comment: you already have the url, so call this function with the url you generated by replacing `window.location.replace(url);` with `openTab(url)`.

Comment: I did this but nothing happens now. Links are clickable but doesn't go anywhere.

Comment: do your browser block it? check it on address bar

Comment: Sorry but how do I check this? When I tried clicking on one of the buttons, the address bar doesn't change. It is clickable though (by the change in cursor)

Comment: for more details visit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript

Comment: Solved. Thanks so much PhuLuong. That link helped!